# How to create an index for the column "ContentTypeId"?

Tags: content-type, index

I use CAML queries to find items by "ContentTypeId".

How can I create an index for this column? In the user interface I can only select "Content Type", not the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SPField.Indexable` Property to check whether `ContentTypeId` field can be indexed or not. Per this http://iedaddy.com/2010/11/sharepoint-2010indexing-columns-in-a-sharepoint-list/ Content type ID cannot be indexed. However, one of the comments mentions that

> Creating an index on “ContentType” really creates an index on
>   “ContentTypeId”, that makes searching for a contenttype in a
>   sitecollection much faster.

Comment: I checked the "SPField.Indexable" property by code. ContentTypeId => true, ContentType => false. I think its because "ContentType" is a "computed" field that relies on "ContentTypeId".